# Why is <img> width not updated properly inside flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a very weird behavior that I cannot explain:

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a flexbox container with non-empty `<div>` and `<img>` inside of it, set `<img>` width to absolute value, like `150px`.
2. Disable cache and enable network throttling in browser web inspector. Both these actions are required.
3. Refresh the HTML document (or "Run" the JSFiddle)

## Example

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">Text text text</div>
  <img class="second" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmmrB.png">
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6zes5yc/

## Expected result:

Image width is equal to what is set in CSS, e. g. `150px`

[image: expected behavior]

## Actual  result:

Image is **shrunk**...

[image: actual behavior]

...**but it immediately updates the width if resize the window** (!). Web inspector shows that its width does not correspond to the width set in CSS:

[image: calculated width value]

If I resize the document, or change browser tab and go back, image width changes to normal value (!). If this doesn't happen, I would think that I don't understand something in flexbox rules about how is flexbox elements width calculated. But the fact that browser displays document differently when I switch to another tab and go back looks very weird. Is it a bug in browsers? **What is the explanation for this behavior?**

Tested on:

- Opera 64.0.3417.92
- Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108
- Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1

In falkon 3.1.0 it works as expected

Note: declaring `min-width`/`max-width` with the same value as `width` or `flex-shrink: 0` allows to "hide" the "problem". But a real problem is a lack of understanding why does this happen.

Comment: what if you add `flex-shrink:0` to the image?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it works. Actually, we have already found this work-around. But it does not explain why do browsers behave so weird (?)

Comment: it's diffuclt to answer since this happen in a very particular case. Maybe it's a *shared* bug

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @TemaniAfif why "very particular"? It's just a flexbox with text block and image. Network throttling is necessary only to make the behavior *stable*. In original project we had observed this bug even without network throttling, although it wasn't stable

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    Open "Network" tab in browser web inspector.
    Set "disable cache" and enable network throttling ("Fast 3G" works for me).
    Make viewport narrow enough; there must not be free space in flex container.
    Run the jsfiddle.
    See that image width is LESS then 150px.
    Resize the window a bit.
    See that image width become 150px now.
  </div>
  <img class="second" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmmrB.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this code, so what? Looks like the only difference is the `flex-shrink: 0`. It is already noted in the question, that `flex-shrink: 0` is possible workaround. It does not explain anything.

Comment: In flex it tries to adjust the content so that it is adjusted within the flex container and the text is too long so it shrink the image.

Comment: If image is expected to shrink, why doesn't it keep being shrunk when I resize the document? Read the full question, please. It's not about "why does flexbox can shrink it's elements"